# Extrude along Local axis (Blender 3.1)

Tags: extrude, axis

**Problem**:
I have an existing object. So when I'm trying to extrude the edges along the Local axis, the program let me do this only along the Global ones.
I know how to switch between the Global and the Local axis transformation. But it doesn't work with the objects I've already created.
However, when I create a new object, the extrusion along the Local axis works fine.

**The question**:
What should I switch on or switch off to make extrusion normally?

[image]

[image]

Comment: "normally" this should work. Can you pls provide a blend file (you can delete everything except the object which doesn't work) and upload it: open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions. Also a small sketch would be great, in which direction you want to extrude. You can "paint" very easy in Blender just by holding "D" and holding your mouse key and paint ;)

Comment: you can try to select your face -> ctrl - E -> along normals. This works normally.

Comment: Regarding the direction.
Try to extrude the windows frame along its direction view (45degree toward ZY axes).
Another example is exhausting pipes. I can't extrude the edges straight along its direction. (Everything you'll find in blender file)

And thank You very much!

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=nBgdPqvK" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/nBgdPqvK/)

Comment: Ohh, I found a solution.
I can not extrude just the edges (window frame for example), it doesn't find the way. When I fulfill the space, the problem disappears. Now I can extrude the whole face toward the view direction (ZY axis). It's inconvenient, but it works.
The same with any other objects, except the new cube...
It's strange...
But the last version of Blender didn't have it.